# Python type hints: How to use Literal with strings to conform with mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, literals

I want to restrict the possible input arguments by using `typing.Literal`.

The following code works just fine, however, `mypy` is complaining.

```
from typing import Literal


def literal_func(string_input: Literal["best", "worst"]) -> int:
    if string_input == "best":
        return 1
    elif string_input == "worst":
        return 0


literal_func(string_input="best")  # works just fine with mypy

# The following call leads to an error with mypy:
# error: Argument "string_input" to "literal_func" has incompatible type "str";
# expected "Literal['best', 'worst']"  [arg-type]

input_string = "best"
literal_func(string_input=input_string)
```

Comment: `input_string`'s inferred type is just `str`, if you don't want to inline it you'll have to explicitly provide a narrower type to prevent reassignment to a value that isn't "best" (or "worst").

Comment: mypy is correct in your case:
`input_string` is not a Literal, but a variable of type `str`. Try defining the literal_func with a string input type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, **mypy** does not narrow the type of `input_string` to `Literal["best"]`. You can help it with a proper type annotation:

```py
input_string: Literal["best"] = "best"
literal_func(string_input=input_string)
```

Perhaps worth mentioning that [**pyright**](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) works just fine with your example.

---

Alternatively, the same can be achieved by annotating the `input_string` as `Final`:

```py
from typing import Final, Literal

...

input_string: Final = "best"
literal_func(string_input=input_string)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, I don't understand why ``mypy`` isn't complaining when I  directly submit a ``str`` as in ``literal_func("best")``? Where is the difference in putting this ``str`` in a variable and pass it on?

Comment: My guess is that in `input_string = "best"` mypy infers the `str` type, without further narrowing, since the variable can be modified later to a different `str` value. Thus, in a direct call with a literal `literal_func("best")` it can "safely" narrow the type to a literal.

Comment: @Andi when you do `x = 'foo'`, for `mypy` it is essentially the same as declaration `x: string`. `mypy` does not do weird jumping stuff like typescript compiler or pyright, which first try to infer literal type and then re-define it as string on reassignment only - it just says "without explicit annotation, we can't know if it will be re-assigned first, and literals are rare enough - so just consider it a string". With `Final` modificator, it knows for sure that reassignment is denied - so literal inference is safe. In direct call it checks if `'best' is compatible with 'best'` instead.